# How can I assure my domain entity's method was called before other method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

I want to write a test that assures that a method of my domain entity was called before the repository method, so I can guarantee the information was changed before being persisted.

So in my sample domain service implementation, I inverted the orders of the calls, so I could see the test failing.

```
using NSubstitute;
using Xunit;

namespace MyProject
{
    public interface IMyService
    {
        void MyServiceMethod(MyEntity entity);
    }

    public interface IMyRepository
    {
        void Persist(MyEntity entity);
    }

    public class MyEntity
    {
        public string MyProp { get; private set; }

        public void ChangeMyProp(string newValue)
        {
            MyProp = newValue;
        }
    }

    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;
        public MyService(IMyRepository repository)
        {
            _myRepository = repository;
        }

        public void MyServiceMethod(MyEntity entity)
        {
            _myRepository.Persist(entity); // this is a wrong fake implementation that should me caught on test
            entity.ChangeMyProp("I am changing you");
        }
    }

    public class MyServiceTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void MyServiceMethod_Should_ChangeProp_Before_Persists()
        {
            var repository = Substitute.For<IMyRepository>();
            var service = new MyService(repository);
            var myEntity = new MyEntity();

            service.MyServiceMethod(myEntity);

            Received.InOrder(() =>
            {
                myEntity.ChangeMyProp("I am changing you");
                repository.Persist(myEntity);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this tests is passing. The only thing I can think about is writing an interface for my `MyEntity` or make that method virtual, so maybe nsubstitute can deal with that, but that sounds not good for me because this is my domain entity and nobody outside domain should make implementations or override this logic.

Any way I can test this calls order?

PS: If you only know how to that with Moq or other Mock library, it's not a problem. It will help me as well. I can change it.

**Edit**

I also tried the following code and it didn't work. This also passed.

```
repository.Received().Persist(Arg.Is<MyEntity>(e => e.MyProp == "I am changing you"));
```

**Edit 2**

I found a related issue on github that helped me to solve the problem and I posted an answer. Although I don't like that solution since is not very clean for me, but it's okay, it's all I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could just verify what the Persist method is receiving. If the received entity has the changed value, you know the order was correct.
Verifying a method call to an object that cannot be mocked is always difficult and usually points to a design issue.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/216).

```
    [Fact]
    public void MyServiceMethod_Should_ChangeProp_Before_Persists()
    {
        var repository = Substitute.For<IMyRepository>();
        var service = new MyService(repository);
        var myEntity = new MyEntity();
        var namePersisted = string.Empty;

        repository.Persist(Arg.Do<MyEntity>(e => namePersisted = e.MyProp));
        service.MyServiceMethod(myEntity);

        Assert.Equal(myEntity.MyProp, namePersisted);
    }
```